# Nested If Statements Returning zero if nothing entered in cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Listed below is the formula. I would like to return zero if nothing is entered in the cell.How would i do this?

```
=IF(E6>0,F6/E6,"")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E6),0,IF(E6>0,F6/E6,""))
```